# Call a function without adding to undo list

Tags: vim

Before I save a file, I have vim set up to trim whitespace from the end of lines and make sure there is only one blank line at the end of the file if I'm editing a .py file. However, function calls end up in the undo history; how can I run these functions without being able to undo them?

```
fun! <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    %s/\s\+$//e
    call cursor(l, c)
endfun

autocmd FileType * autocmd BufWritePre <buffer> :call <SID>StripTrailingWhitespaces()

function TrimEndLines()
    let save_cursor = getpos(".")
    :silent! %s#\($\n\s*\)\+\%$##
    call setpos('.', save_cursor)
endfunction

au BufWritePre * call TrimEndLines()

function AppendEndLine()
    let save_cursor = getpos(".")
    :silent! %s/^\(.*\)\%$/\1\r/
    call setpos(".", save_cursor)
endfunction

au BufWritePre * call AppendEndLine()
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want an extra blank line at the end of python scripts?

Comment: Lots of reasons, here's a good summary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729692/why-should-files-end-with-a-newline And PEP8 recommends it.

Comment: Hmm… no, there's no mention of that recommendation in PEP8 and if there was a recommendation it would be to have the last line of the file end with a newline character, not to be empty. Vim already ends every line with a newline character unless you tell it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot disable undo without losing the undo history. Think about the undo implementation; would be pretty hard if you had a gap in there.

If you don't worry about losing the history,

```
:set undolevels=-1
```

(and then restoring to the previous value) will do.

Also, `:undojoin` can be used to fuse two otherwise separate entries together. But in your situation, it's probably best to keep the (automated) change inside the undo history.

PS: There are plugins that implement the trailing whitespace removal in a more robust way, e.g. my [DeleteTrailingWhitespace plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3967). (The plugin page has links to alternative plugins.)